# How to manipulate strings and array in Apache Velocity request mapping template in AWS appSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, apache-velocity

This is my first time working with VTL, so please correct my code if there is something very silly in it.

**What I want to achieve**

```
{
    "cities": ["jaipur", "mumbai", "delhi", "sheros", "jalandhar", "bengaluru"]
}
```

Graphql schema:

```
type Query{
  getCitiesForGroups: String
}
```

Default response template:

```
#if($ctx.error)
    $utils.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end
    $utils.toJson($utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0])
```

Using the default response template, the result I was getting

```
{ "data": { "getCitiesForGroups": [ "{groupcity=jaipur}", "{groupcity=mumbai}", "{groupcity=delhi}", "{groupcity=sheros}", "{groupcity=jalandhar}", "{groupcity=bengaluru}" ] } }
```

My request template

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "statements": [
        "select DISTINCT LOWER(city) as city from public.Groups"
    ]
}
```

To get the desired output, I changed the response template as I wanted to loop over the response I got from the DB, and remove the `{city=}` from the string by using the substring method given [in AWS resolver mapping docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-programming-guide.html#strings) and this is where I am facing the problem.

My response template

```
#if($ctx.error)
    $utils.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end
#set ($rawListOfCities = $utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0])
#set ($sanitisedListOfCities = [])
#foreach( $city in $rawListOfCities )
    #set ($equalToIndex = $city.indexOf("="))
    #set ($equalToIndex = $equalToIndex + 1)
    #set ($curlyLastIndex = $city.lastIndexOf("}"))
    #set ($tempCity = $city.substring($equalToIndex, $curlyLastIndex))
    ## #set ($tempCity = $city)
    $util.qr($sanitisedListOfCities.add($tempCity))
#end
$util.toJson($sanitisedListOfCities)
```

The response that I am getting:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getCitiesForGroups": "[null, null, null, null, null, null]"
  }
}
```

However, when I use the line `#set ($tempCity = $city)` and comment out the line above it, I get the following response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getCitiesForGroups": "[{city=jaipur}, {city=mumbai}, {city=delhi}, {city=sheros}, {city=jalandhar}, {city=bengaluru}]"
  }
}
```

Which means `$city` has the value `{city=jaipur}`, so which I want to sanitize and add it to `($sanitisedListOfCities)` and return it as the response.

But I am getting `null` as the result substring method.

So how can I sanitize the response from DB and return it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue and this is how I solved it.

First, your Graphql schema should look like,

```
type Query {
    getCitiesForGroups: cityList
}

type cityList {
    cities: [String]
}
```

Your request mapping template,

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "statements": [
        "select DISTINCT LOWER(city) as city from public.Groups"
    ]
}
```

And finally your response mapping template

```
#set($cityList = [])
#set($resMap = {})
#if($ctx.error)
    $utils.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end

#foreach($item in $utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0])
    $util.qr($cityList.add($item.city))
#end
$util.qr($resMap.put("cities", $cityList))

#return($resMap)
```

Expected response(complete)

```
{
  "data": {
    "getCitiesForGroups": {
      "cities": [
        "jaipur",
        "mumbai",
        "delhi",
        "sheros",
        "jalandhar",
        "bengaluru"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Your solution works like a charm. Thank you so much for helping out. Can you please point me to some resources so I can understand this all much better? Thank you once again.

Comment: Glad to help you. I usually refer to AWS Developer Guide, Stackoverflow and sometimes AWS Discussion forum. Other than that, Adrian Hall and Nader Dabit have some amazing tutorials and guides on AppSync; you should also check them out!